# Bad number of lines EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, android-edittext

I am trying to create a simple system for displaying the number of lines in an edittext via a TextView layout. Unfortunately, when I display the layout, the number of lines is calculated from the old dimension of the edittext and not from the new one, this results in a wrong number of lines.

---

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey100"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/textView"
                android:gravity="start|top"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editText;
    private TextView textView;
    private int lineNumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        editText.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.");

        showLine();
    }

    private void showLine() {
        editText.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                editText.invalidate();
                editText.requestLayout();
                lineNumber = editText.getLineCount();
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < lineNumber; i ++)
                    text.append(i+1).append("\n");

                textView.setText(text.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what do mean by old dimension of the edittext? What is your expected output here?

Comment: I think that the RelativeLayout isn't actualize, which means that the lines are calculated according to the old size of my edittext and not the new one or the edittext at 50dp in months (due to the change in visibility of the textview)